# Linux kernel module does not load after applying device-tree overlay via configfs

Tags: linux, driver, overlay, device-tree

I have a Linux driver module compiled at some random location (e.g. `/home/user/sample-driver.ko`). Devices that use this module are defined in the device-tree overlay file. I want to load this driver when the overlay is applied. I did the following steps:

1. Move `sample-driver.ko` to `/lib/modules/<version>/kernel/drivers/iio/dac/sample-driver.ko`
2. Run `depmod` (no arguments)
3. Apply device-tree overlay via `configfs`

At this point the module should be loaded and `iio:deviceX` visible in `/dev` directory. However, the module is not loaded. **Module can be manually probed** with `modprobe sample-driver`.

What I tried:

- compatible strings are in the `modules.alias` file.
- manually added `kernel/drivers/iio/dac/sample-driver.ko` to `modules.order`.

But nothing works. Where can be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe there are some potential issues,

- check the module dependencies and  run `modinfo sample-driver.ko` to show dependencies
- check the module version , your driver module was compiled for a different kernel version you can check kernel version to running `uname -r` command
- check the module permissions, You can check the permissions with the command `ls -l`
- loading order, check the the driver module is being loaded after any dependencies that it may have. You can check the module loading order with the `lsmod` command
- run `dmesg`  this command and give you more information about why the module is not being loaded automatically.
- check the modprobe configuration, maybe check the /etc/modprobe.d/ directory for any files that may be blacklisting your module.
- try manually loading the module with  this command `insmod /lib/modules/$(uname -r)/kernel/drivers/iio/dac/sample-driver.ko`
- check the device tree overlay
- verify that the module is built correctly `make and make install`

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Module has no dependencies (modinfo depends: is empty). Module version match `uname -r`. Module permissions are same as others. Nothing in the dmesg ("Deviec XXX is probed..." sholud be displayed.). Driver name is not in `lsmod`.

Comment: Also, another driver, that was build and was installed properly with `modules_install` is probed when the overlay is applied.

Comment: @Juraj Maybe update module dependecy,  Even though your module has no dependencies, you can still update the module dependencies by running `depmod -a`